# sqlite: select subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to prepare select subquery on folders table which has below columns :

workspace_Id  
parent_Id

my requirement is :

1 ) I need all the folders of a particular workspace_id say workspace_id='xyz'  
for example : 
 `select * from folders where workspace_id='xyz'`

now I get the result like below :

```
id  workspace_id parent_id
1   xyz          51
2   xyz          44
3   xyz          73 
4   xyz          NULL
5   xyz          90
6   xyz          NULL
```

2) Now lets say 51 and 90 is not present in the db.
for example :

```
select * from folders where workspace_id='xyz' and parent_id=51
```

or

```
select * from folders where workspace_id='xyz' and parent_id=90
```

I should not get anything from the above 2 queries because 51 and 90 is not present in db.

2) tricky part : my requirement is to fetch only those folders which has parent_id which is not present in the db or null

I am confused if its possible with self join or subquery would be enough, I should really learn subqueries and join :(

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Comment: First you say that the values 51 and 90 are in the table. Then you say they aren't.

Comment: @jarlh what I am trying to say is there are child folders and parent folders but I want to fetch those folders whose parent folders doesn't exist in the db, for example (51 and 90) are parent folders but they really doesn't exist in the db, folder 1 and folder 5 has non existing parents or you can say they are just dummy pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `not exists` is almost a direct translation of your description of what you want:

```
select f.*
from folders f
where workspace_id = 'xyz' and
      (parent_id is null or
       not exists (select 1 from folders f2 where f2.id = f.parent_id)
      );
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you please tell me why you used 1 in the subquery ?

Comment: `EXISTS` checks only if the subquery returns any row, so it does not matter what the value in that row it.

Comment: @Soumyaansh . . . I always use `select 1` for `exists` and `not exists`.  The only important thing is whether a row exists, not the value that is returned.